# XGBoost - worse accuracy when increasing sample size? Survival analysis on a large dataset

Tags: survival, modeling, boosting, large-data

I've encountered the above problem and struggle to find any info about online.

I'm messing around with a large dataset that I unfortunately cannot share. It has ~600 features of which not all are informative and there is some collinearity. There is upward of 150k samples with imbalanced, right-censored survival data where the target endpoint is met in around 2% of the samples. I'm using an XGBoost regressor with 'survival:cox' as objective and I'm running K-fold cross-validation with an inner loop for hyperparameter tuning and an outer loop for performance evaluation.

When starting out with a small subsample of the data predictive accuracy is ok, but when increasing the sample size over a certain threshold (around 20-30k) the evaluation performance starts to deteriorate. Training accuracy also goes down so it seems to be an underfitting problem.

I'm thinking of trying to reduce the number of features, and/or reducing the class imbalance by subsampling.

Happy for any insights to the nature of the problem, which I fail to understand, and possible solutions!

Comment: it sounds like an underfitting problem, as you suggest, but then none of your solutions address that.  read up about xgboost (how do you create more complex models?).  I am guessing that you have to adjust the model parameters as you increase your data, eg increase tree depth.

Comment: Thank you Sean. Yes, I can see that. I will try adding more complexity to the model. What I can't see is how it can underfit so much that accuracy actually gets worse with more data.. In my mind, more samples to train on would always lead to better fit, but maybe I'm wrong there.

Comment: imagine you have 1 feature and a max tree depth of 5, then you can create 32 leaves, so you can fit any 32 data points perfectly. if 1 start adding points my accuracy will go down.